# Show message from inbox by modal in php

Tags: javascript, php, allow-modals

I made an inbox by making arrays ($from_user_array,  $type_array, $subject_array and $message_array) and showing what's in the arrays by putting it in an html table with a for loop. i've copied code from w3schools to make the modals. I know the mistake must be somewhere in the following code because everything else works:

```
 <?php foreach(range(0,$rowcount-1) as $i): ?>
    <tr>
<td><?php echo $from_user_array[$i]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $type_array[$i]; ?></td>
<td><button id = "<?php echo $i; ?>" onclick="click("<?php echo $i; ?>")"> 
 Click to open</button></td>
 </tr>

 function click(ide){
 <?php echo $i; ?>
 // Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById(ide);

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
}
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

<div class="modal-content">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
<p><b> subject: </b></p> </br>
<?php echo $subject_array[$i]; ?>
<p><b> message: </b></p> </br>
<?php echo $message_array[$i]; ?>
 </div>

 </div>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

anybody knows whats the problem?

Comment: the function click(ide) should be inside <script> tag

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: make a fiddle with all the code

Comment: i don't know what a fiddle is, but if you give me your email i will send you my code and 5 euro if you solve my problem.

Comment: give me yours , i will mail you :)

Comment: prinsjur@gmail.com

Comment: @jurriaanprins: it is in the spirit of Stack Overflow if you can have your conversation on this platform, with folks helping you being encouraged to provide the answer here. Hiding the solution in a private conversation means that future readers will not be helped, but helping them is our primary purpose here.

Comment: @halfer I'm sorry. The problem was that there was php in my javascript